# Is rmic still needed?

Tags: java, rmi

Is it true that the rmi interface compiler is not needed for java 1.5 or newer and that just compiling the java file where the UnicastRemoteObject is defined with javac is enough?Rmic still works and it generates a stub class file if you give it the class file of the implementation of the remote object.

Answer (score 7):

According to the RMI tutorial:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html

> Compiling Sources
>
> As with any Java program, you use the
>   javac compiler to compile the source
>   files. The source files contain the
>   declarations of the remote interfaces,
>   their implementations, any other
>   server classes, and the client
>   classes. Note: With versions prior to
>   Java Platform, Standard Edition 5.0,
>   an additional step was required to
>   build stub classes, by using the rmic
>   compiler. However, this step is no
>   longer necessary.

Comment: But when **Server** is executed without Stub class, it gives **StubNotFoundException**.

Comment: Exception occured when using exportObject(object) but not when exportObject(object,0);

Comment: The tutorial is wrong. See the preamble to the Javadoc for `UnicastRemoteObiect`. You can avoid using `rmic` under specific circumstances, i.e. when you construct or export the remote object providing a port number parameter (even zero), for reasons described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

See the preamble to the Javadoc for `UnicastRemoteObiect`. You can avoid using `rmic` under specific circumstances, i.e. when you construct or export the remote object providing a port number parameter (even zero), for reasons described in the documentation.