# Java inter-process communication in year 2015 (with no boiler-plate)?

Tags: java, serialization, process, rpc

My use-case:

- process-1 "database" that loads >1GB of data into memory from data-files (just the loading takes 30-60 seconds)
- process-2 "client" wants to access that data quickly without having to load it all

They are separate processes ran on same machine. Data I would like to transfer between the processes is Collections (lists, maps) containing primitive-types (integers, strings, booleans).

I know that this can be done by opening socket-connect (creating some specific protocol in serializing the data) or by RMI (more or less the same thing). We did both of these already 15 years ago. Hasn't anyone automatized this by now so that by using some library you could just set up `@InterProcessMethod("some", "details")` and be able to invoke methods on different JVM without having to implement serializations etc. each time? (because of the primary types this shouldn't be too complex).

A company called Caucho used to have some product to tackle this issue but I cannot find it from their webpage anymore. Then again, it was a sort of web-service instead RPC.

Comment: OK, I like this question.

Comment: No they haven't ... because the problem is more complicated than you imagine.

Comment: A good question. Yet off-topic.

Comment: If I understand it right, the only way would be if Oracle itself embeds it in the JVM. No external library could do this.

Comment: All the data types you have mentioned are already `Serializable,` so your major stated issue disappears. But I would question the design. You should be using a database for the database, not a process that loads it all into memory. There isn't really any point to that if you have to then retransmit it to another process.

Comment: RMI is still the best way to do it, especially now that [rmic isn't needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702882/is-rmic-still-needed).  Another option is JAX-WS: make the SEI class available to both processes, and have the server publish an [Endpoint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html).

Comment: This isn't meant to be anything production-suitable but more or less technology-demo for me to all the new frameworks and libraries that have be released in past years that I haven't used yet.

RMI (with existing serialisation) or JSON/Jackson are both ok solutions, as long as I don't have to do any heavy-lifting myself (I can do it, I am just looking for easier solutions).

Comment: So the solution I was looking for was in fact:
- include some library (that I wasn't aware of before) to the project
- add some @Annotations to the methods to server/client classes

Just invoke the code like it would be local classes (maybe with added asynchronous handling).

Answer (score 0):

Not that I now of. The more "2015" would be to stay with RMI, or, refactor your backend into a REST API and connect it via JSON, and then, if you want, serialize/deserialize it with Jackson or even by hand (In some very performance oriented scenarios).